# Vectorial space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Show that a normed vector space(NVE) $(X,\|\cdot \|)$,then the  operation, $+:X^2 \rightarrow X$ and   $\cdot : \mathbb{K}*X \rightarrow X$ are continuous?

when $(u,v)\in X*Y $(NVE) $\|(u,v)\|_p =\sqrt[p]{\|u\|_X^p + \|v\|_Y^p}$

Help me please because I can´t beginne.

Comment: What does (NVE) mean?

Comment: Also, did you mean to write
$$
\|(u,v)\|_p =\sqrt[p]{\|u\|_X^p + \|v\|_Y^p}?
$$

Comment: yes, and (NEV) normed vector space

Comment: A good way to start is by writing out the definition of continuity.  It is easier to show that $+$ is continuous.

Comment: this definition?

Comment: $f \text{is continue in} a \text{iff} \forall(x_n\in D(f),) (x_n \rightarrow a \in (X,d_x)) \Rightarrow (f(x_n)\rightarrow f(a) \in (Y,d_y))$

Comment: Right, but replace the pieces of that definitions with the specifics for $f = +$

Comment: but $+(x,y)=x+y $?

Comment: exactly. $+$ is a map from the space $X \times X$ to the space $X$.

Comment: I can not use the definition correctly, I need that, you can help me please

Comment: and In the case of the product, is this correct? $\cdot:\mathbb{K}*X \rightarrow X$ , $\alpha u \rightarrow \sqrt[p]{\| \alpha u\|_x^p} $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** (for $+$) By the definition of continuity, you need to show that given any sequence $z_n$ in $X \times X$ with $z_n \to z$, we have $+(z_n) \to +(z)$. In other words, we need to show that for any two sequences $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$: if the sequence $(u_n,v_n) \to (u,v)$ in $X \times X$, then $u_n+v_n \to u + v$.

Proceed as follows:

- Show that if $(u_n,v_n) \to (u,v)$, then $u_n \to u$ and $v_n \to v$.
- Show that if $u_n \to u$ and $v_n \to v$, then $u_n + v_n \to u+v$.

**Hint:** (for $*$) similarly, we need to show that for any sequence $k_n$ in $\Bbb K$ and any sequence $u_n$ in $X$: if the sequence $(k_n,u_n) \to (k,u)$, then $k_n u_n \to ku$.

Proceed as follows:

- Show that if $(k_n,u_n) \to (k,u)$, then $k_n \to k$ and $u_n \to u$.
- Show that if $k_n\to k$ and $u_n \to u$, then $k_nu_n \to ku$.

Comment: thanks, now  (for ∗) the definition is, $(\alpha_n, u_n)\in \mathbb{K}*X \text{then} \|(\alpha_n, u_n)\|_p = \sqrt[p]{\| \alpha_n\|_x^p +\|u_n\|_y^p}$ this is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct